# Aggregation, grouping error even using OVER PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting this error

> 'PRINTING_DATE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

but by using `OVER PARTITION BY` I expected this issues won't appear, why am I still getting this error?

```
DECLARE @REPORT AS NVARCHAR(50) = '2019-06-19 00:00:00.000'

SELECT 
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN (P_DATE < @REPORT AND P_DATE > DATEADD(DAY, -7, @REPORT)) 
              THEN QTY_PICKED 
              ELSE 0 
        END) OVER (PARTITION BY PLANT, PARTS, P_DATE) AS SHIPPED,
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN E_DATE > @REPORT AND E_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @REPORT) 
              THEN QTY_MII 
              ELSE 0 
        END) - SUM(CASE 
                      WHEN E_DATE > @REPORT AND E_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @REPORT) 
                         THEN QTY_PICKED 
                         ELSE 0 
                   END) AS TO_SHIP
FROM
    TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN
    TABLE2 T2 ON T1.DELIVERY = T2.DELIVERY
WHERE 
    PLANT = 'XXX'
```

Comment: ***WHY oh why*** are you storing a **date&time** as a `NVARCHAR(50)` variable?!?!?!?? You should **ALWAYS** use the **most appropriate** datatype - and here, that would **clearly** be a `DATETIME2(0)` or a `DATE` (if you don't need the time portion) - but most certainly not a `NVARCHAR(50)`!!

Comment: You are only using `OVER PARTITION BY` for one of the sums, the others still need a `group by`

Comment: but the error is for the first SUM..error line point to the first SUM

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000588/calculate-totals-based-on-different-grouping-conditions     kindly refer to this post

Answer (score 0):

As HoneyBadger pointed out, you only have a "OVER PARTITION BY" in the first SUM, not the second.

Try this as a simplified version:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(PLANT INT,PARTS INT,P_DATE DATE,QTY1 INT, QTY2 INT)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES(1,1,'2019-07-03',40,60)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES(1,1,'2019-07-03',50,80)

SELECT 
     SUM(QTY1) OVER (PARTITION BY PLANT, PARTS, P_DATE) AS SHIPPED
    ,SUM(QTY1) OVER (PARTITION BY PLANT, PARTS, P_DATE) - 
      SUM(QTY2) OVER (PARTITION BY PLANT, PARTS, P_DATE) AS TOSHIP
    ,SUM(QTY1)  -  SUM(QTY2) AS TOSHIP2
FROM  @T1
WHERE PLANT = 1
```

This will raise an error: 
Column '@T1.PLANT' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
If you comment/delete the line

```
,SUM(QTY1)  -  SUM(QTY2) AS TOSHIP2
```

it will produce a result.
BTW: in this example the error also points to the first SUM, but this one is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather unclear what you are trying to do.  But I can give a hint:  window functions are of no use if your result set is an aggregation that returns a single row.

So, you might want this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (P_DATE < @REPORT AND P_DATE > DATEADD(DAY, -7, @REPORT)) 
                THEN QTY_PICKED 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS SHIPPED,
          (SUM(CASE WHEN E_DATE > @REPORT AND E_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @REPORT) 
                   THEN QTY_MII 
                   ELSE 0 
               END) -
           SUM(CASE WHEN E_DATE > @REPORT AND E_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @REPORT) 
                    THEN QTY_PICKED 
                    ELSE 0 
               END)
          ) AS TO_SHIP
FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN
     TABLE2 T2
     ON T1.DELIVERY = T2.DELIVERY
WHERE PLANT = 'XXX';
```

Of course, you might want an aggregation query that returns more than one row:

```
SELECT PLANT, PARTS, P_DATE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (P_DATE < @REPORT AND P_DATE > DATEADD(DAY, -7, @REPORT)) 
                THEN QTY_PICKED 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS SHIPPED,
          (SUM(CASE WHEN E_DATE > @REPORT AND E_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @REPORT) 
                   THEN QTY_MII 
                   ELSE 0 
               END) -
           SUM(CASE WHEN E_DATE > @REPORT AND E_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @REPORT) 
                    THEN QTY_PICKED 
                    ELSE 0 
               END)
          ) AS TO_SHIP
FROM TABLE1 T1 INNER JOIN
     TABLE2 T2
     ON T1.DELIVERY = T2.DELIVERY
WHERE PLANT = 'XXX'
GROUP BY PLANT, PARTS, P_DATE;
```